# How to properly implement a form that is using the jQuery UI autocomplete widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and the [jquery-rails 2.1.3](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) (including jQuery UI). I am trying to implement a HTML form so to search, select and submit city data by using the [Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete) jQuery UI widget.

At this time I am implementing my form with the following "autocompletable" field:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="cities">City: </label>
  <input id="cities" />
</div>

<script>
  $jQ(function() {
    var cache = {};
    $jQ( "#cities" ).autocomplete({
      autoFocus: true,
      minLength: 3,
      source:    function( request, response ) {
        $jQ.ajax({
            url:      '<SEARCH_PATH>',
            data:     { search: request.term },
            dataType: 'json',
            success:  function(data) {
              var cities = new Array();

              $jQ.each(data, function(arrayID, city) {
                cities.push({ label: city.name, value: city.id })
              });

              response( cities ); 
            },
            error:    function () {
              response([]);
            }
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

The above code works as expected for retrieving JSON data and displaying the list of retrieved cities. As you can see, the "useful part" of city data is the `id` of the city since I am using the `id` value in order to handle internally the submitted data. However, given the "selectable" list of cities is displayed, when I use keyboard UP and DOWN arrows in order to select one of those cities then the input field is populated with the city `id` (not with the city `name`).

I would like to:

- *display the city `name` instead of the `id` in the input field on selecting the city;*
- *find a way in order to submit the city `id` and not the city `name`* (even if the city `name` is the only thing displayed in the front end content).

How could / should I make to properly accomplish that?

Comment: It's not absolutely clear, but it sounds almost as-if you want the default functionality of the autocomplete.

Comment: @Kevin B - I don't think so since, *for instance*, the default functionality related to the [select](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) event of the Autocomplete widget "is to replace the text field's value with the value of the selected item". In this case, as I wrote in the question, I would like to display the city `name` (the `label`) instead of the `id` (the `value`) in the input field on selecting the city.

Comment: It seems to be working for me, at this fiddle, type `f` and choose foo, and `bar` appears in the input. http://jsfiddle.net/f8yPX/

Comment: @Kevin B - Your linked code is *not* what I am looking for. However, considering your case, I would like *still to display* the `foo` label (on selecting `foo`) but *submit* the `bar` value when I submit the related form.

Comment: On select, populate a hidden input with your desired value and submit that hidden input rather than the autocomplete.

Comment: ... with the select event of the autocomplete. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Comment: @Kevin B - I tried to implement the `select` event, but I have troubles on making it to work as expected. It is for that reason that I asked "How?" in my previous comment and I posted the question at all.

Comment: Granted, the api isn't very clear on how to bind to the events. The easy way is to pass it into the options object: `{ select: function }`

Comment: @Kevin B - The `{ select: function }` code is the "basic code" to implement the `select` event (I already used-tried that*!*) but I don't know how to proceed (for example, how to *retrieve* and *handle* related objects?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the select event to populate a hidden field, then submit the hidden field instead.

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="cities">City: </label>
  <input id="cities" />
  <input name="cities" type="hidden" id="cities-hidden" />
</div>
```

js

```
$jQ(function() {
  var cache = {};
  $jQ( "#cities" ).autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    ...
    select: function(e, ui) {
      $("#cities-hidden").val(ui.item.value); // populate hidden input
      $("#cities").val(ui.item.label); // populate autocomplete input
      return false; // prevent default action of populating autocomplete input with value
    }
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f8yPX/3/

Comment: What's up with the syntax highlighter today?

Comment: Your code seems to work, but what do you mean with "What's up with the syntax highlighter today"?

Comment: It's highlighting the code incorrectly for some reason, even though the code is syntactically valid. Not related to the question.

Comment: There is a subtle (visible) issue on selecting a value: when you use UP / DOWN keyboard arrows in the autocompletable field it is displayed the `value` of the selected item until I don't select definitively the item. It should always be displayed the `label` (not the `value`). The is, the end user should never see the `value`.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand what you are referring to when you say "it's highlighting the code incorrectly for some reason, even though the code is syntactically valid".

Comment: Do you see in my code (and yours) how the color of label is black on the opening and red on the closing? that is incorrect. tagNames and attributeNames should all be consistently black or red. Again, not related to your question.

Comment: (If I understand you) No, I don't see the color change... However (first of all, thank you), can you even help me to solve the problem with the "subtle" issue described in the previous comment?

Comment: There's no event for that, so i'm not aware of a quick way of doing that.

Comment: And, at least (so that I can "experiment" / "try" my self to implement something to solve that issue), what approach I can use to make it to always display the `label` (not the `value`) on selecting a item?

Comment: *BTW*: I just opened a new question for the ["subtle" issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236653/how-to-improve-the-autocompletable-jquery-widget-so-to-make-it-to-display-always).